# [EmberJS]: Get selected model in child template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm pretty new to Ember and would like to get a selected models value in child controller/template.

I have a sidebar that lists Workspaces. Whenever someone click on workspace the application routes to `workspaces/:slug`and shows a list of tasks connected to that specific workspace.

I would like to show the selected workspace `name` in the child route. How would I go about doing that?

My router looks like so:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('login');
    this.resource('workspaces', function() {
      this.route('tasks', {path: ':slug'});
    }); 
});
```

Been reading a lot of stuff online but haven't quite figured it out.

Thanks.

Comment: is slug the name of the workspace?

Comment: @KalmanHazins yes. /workspaces/my-workspace for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:slug` is your dynamic segment. You can access your dynamic segment inside your `model` hook like so:

```
App.WorkspacesTasksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(param) {
    return { name: param.slug };
  }
});
```

See a working jsbin example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xirule/1/edit?html,js,console,output)